# Converting list of list to dictionaries with calculated field

Tags: python

```
['1', 'james', '1', '90\n']
['1', 'james', '2', '78\n']
['1', 'james', '3', '87\n']
['1', 'james', '4', '98\n']
['2', 'alice', '1', '95\n']
['2', 'alice', '2', '91\n']
['2', 'alice', '3', '100\n']
['2', 'alice', '4', '98\n']
```

Basically, this is what I have. Bunch of lists read from a text file.
I am trying to figure out a function that outputs something like this to this console.

```
1, james: 88.65 (this number is weigh-adjusted mark for all assignments)
                       *Weight for each assignment 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3
2, alice: 96.15
```

Parameters are student number, name, assignment# and mark respectively.
Each person will have at least four lines in the text file for each assignment#
I am doing this for self-teaching purpose since I am new to Python.
Would much appreciate any help in this case. I can't seem to find any hints from online tutorials

Comment: so these lists are objects or just strings?

Comment: To OP: What have you tried so far? For a lot of people here, this question is very easy to answer, but please do not answer it. Let the OP show some effort.

Comment: I manipulated the text file so that it's shown as list of strings

Comment: Since you are into self-teaching, how about posting the code that you have tried. You will learn more from that than having the answer handed to you on a platter.

Comment: close it until the OP posts his attempt

Comment: I am not looking for the code itself but rather a hint as to what data structure would be most fit and approaches to this Q

Comment: @krnactry you should use a dictionary

Comment: or just leave it as a list and use a combination of groubpy, int and sum, and maybe sorted ... its not clear if this list is sorted , its also not clear if 1 maybe associated with another name later

Comment: You need to group the scores by student and then calculate the sum of the weighted scores. You could use a `collection.defaultdict(float)` or `collection.groupby()` to easily do this, although the former is perhaps easier to work with and doesn't require sorted data.

Comment: When you say "at least four lines," don't you mean "at most four lines"?  How would you handle a student with 6 lines in the file?  I would use `collection.defaultdict(float)` as mhawke suggests.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking how to progress, rather than for the actual code, here are some suggestions on how to attack the problem:

1. Use Python's [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to open your text file.
2. Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to load your data from the file. This would give you your lists as you have them, one per row, and would also mean that the final entry does not include the `\n`.
3. Use the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function with the csv reader, and a key based on the first entry to return you `k` and `g`, where `k` is the key (e.g. `1`), and `g` is an iterator giving you a list of entries matching `1`.
4. You could investigate a list comprehension to then convert these matching lines into a list holding your weighted output.
5. You could then use `sum` on the list to produce your value.
6. You then have all the data to print a line of output.